# how to apply fast exponentiation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

everybody

I have a question in Javascript

that is:

how to realize a fast exponentiation in JS

for example, given three integers, 'm', 'e'.and 'n'

to calculate (m^e)%n.

when Math.pow(m,e) goes very large that JS can't figure the accurate answer(that could happen sometimes), how can we apply fast exponentiation in JS

---

Fast exponentiation is something like if we calculate (m^e)%n, we convert decimal 'e' to binary'e', say, it's 111,

than it comes to  (m*m^2*m4)%n, it equals to ((m%n)*(m^2%n)*(m^4%n))%n, which take the huge calculation apart into small steps.

Comment: Exactly like you would do in C or Java... Can you tell us what you've tried so far? Maybe we could help you.

Comment: You're asking about [Modular exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation). See the wikipedia page for ways to calculate it efficiently.

Comment: first result on google: https://gist.github.com/krzkaczor/0bdba0ee9555659ae5fe